# How can I implement a gpsd client (in C) to get Latitude, Longitude and Altitude?

Tags: c, gps, gpsd

I am writing a number-crunching data-logging C program for my GPS enabled Raspberry Pi. I grabbed [gpsd](https://gpsd.io/), and its sample app cgps displays gps information correctly. I wanted to use [libgps](https://gpsd.io/libgps.html) to interface with the daemon so that I could have all that handy information in my app, but I was quickly overwhelmed by the complexity of its API.

The documentation on its [HOWTO page](https://gpsd.io/client-howto.html) points me to look at [cgps](https://gitlab.com/gpsd/gpsd/-/blob/master/clients/cgps.c) and [gpxlogger](https://gitlab.com/gpsd/gpsd/-/blob/master/clients/gpxlogger.c) for example code, but there's so much coupling that I can't wade through it all. On the opposite end of the spectrum, the C code example on the [libgps](https://gpsd.io/libgps.html) page is so stripped back that it's unusable.

Can anybody point me to a single class sample that might demystify this? Perhaps something that contains a `getCoordinates()` function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I spoke too soon. After browsing other SO questions, I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763424/gpsd-returns-old-data-after-loosing-all-satellites) completely unrelated question. Here's my very slightly modified version:

```
#include <gps.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
struct timeval tv;
struct gps_data_t gps_data;

if ((gps_open("localhost", "2947", &gps_data)) == -1) {
    printf("code: %d, reason: %s\n", errno, gps_errstr(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
gps_stream(&gps_data, WATCH_ENABLE | WATCH_JSON, NULL);

while (1) {
    /* wait for 2 seconds to receive data */
    if (gps_waiting (&gps_data, 2000000)) {
        /* read data */
        if ((gps_read(&gps_data,NULL,0)) == -1) {
            printf("error occured reading gps data. code: %d, reason: %s\n", errno, gps_errstr(errno));
        } else {
            /* Display data from the GPS receiver. */
            if ((gps_data.status == STATUS_FIX) && 
                (gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_2D || gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_3D) &&
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.latitude) && 
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.longitude)) {
                    //gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); EDIT: tv.tv_sec isn't actually the timestamp!
                    printf("latitude: %f, longitude: %f, speed: %f, timestamp: %lf\n", gps_data.fix.latitude, gps_data.fix.longitude, gps_data.fix.speed, gps_data.fix.time); //EDIT: Replaced tv.tv_sec with gps_data.fix.time
            } else {
                printf("no GPS data available\n");
            }
        }
    }

    sleep(3);
}

/* When you are done... */
gps_stream(&gps_data, WATCH_DISABLE, NULL);
gps_close (&gps_data);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile it by running `gcc -o gps filename.c -lm -lgps`

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get gps time?  I'm not too familiar with C but `tv.tv_sec` looks like the system time?

Comment: Probably because I should have used `gps_data.fix.time` instead. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: This is a bit late, but it might prove useful to someone else: you should print the timestamp as an `%lf`. In _gps.h_, the `gps_data.fix.time` is defined as a `timestamp_t`, which is just an alias for a double. Perfect answer otherwise!

Comment: `gps_data.fix.time` is now defined as a `timespec_t` which is a struct timespec with tv_sec and tv_nsec.

Comment: To get a human readable time:

`struct tm ts;
     time_t time = gps_data->fix.time;
     char buf[80];
     
     ts = *localtime(&time);
     strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I would like to offer the following edited version of Nathan's program which demonstrates the **shared memory interface** approach. It took me an afternoon of searching to find the missing key to getting this to work.

EDIT: I corrected the way to properly handle errors from gps_open and gps_read using errno.

```
#include <gps.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
int rc;
//struct timeval tv;
struct gps_data_t gps_data;

if ((gps_open(GPSD_SHARED_MEMORY, NULL, &gps_data)) == -1) {
    printf("code: %d, reason: %s\n", errno, gps_errstr(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        /* read data */
        if ((gps_read(&gps_data,NULL,0)) == -1) {
            printf("error occured reading gps data. code: %d, reason: %s\n", errno, gps_errstr(errno));
        } else {
            /* Display data from the GPS receiver. */
            if ((gps_data.status == STATUS_FIX) && 
                (gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_2D || gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_3D) &&
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.latitude) && 
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.longitude)) {
                    printf("latitude: %f, longitude: %f, speed: %f, timestamp: %lf\n", gps_data.fix.latitude, gps_data.fix.longitude, gps_data.fix.speed, gps_data.fix.time);
            } else {
                printf("no GPS data available\n");
            }
        }

    sleep(3);
}

/* When you are done... */
gps_close (&gps_data);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```