# Connect to a gps deamon server using C#

Tags: c#, gps, gpsd

I am working with a gps connected to a raspberry pi running a gpsd service. I am trying to connect to the service using tcp but I cannot get it to work. I also don't find any documentation about it.

This is the code I have right now:

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        Console.WriteLine($"Trying to connect to {ServerAddress}...");
        var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        client.Connect(ServerAddress, 80);
        var result = new byte[256];
        client.Receive(result);
        Test();
  }
```

Can somebody tell me how it is done, or give me a link to documentation or a c# example.

Comment: Is this [reference](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html) useful?

Comment: I actually read the website you referenced, and it is very usefull when you are using python or c++. But it actually doesn't contain any info for when you are using c#.

Comment: Basically, do you want to translate those C or C++ Examples to C#? Just to better understand: why can't you invoke C++? Are you going to run C# (mono) on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What I am trying to do is actually built a client that connects to the gpsd service. My client is a bigger program that wants to use the gps location of the raspberry pi (remotely). This program is written in c#, and runs on different places.

Comment: So... you could use the standard client on the raspberry pi and build a new network service on the raspberry, to which you could connect in a more standard way from c#. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, but I am also using qgis and that doesn't need the extra service. Is there maybe a way to create a program in c++ and import it into my c# project? That will elimenate the extra delay of the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the section about C Examples from this [source](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html).

The core C client is a socket [receiver](https://github.com/ukyg9e5r6k7gubiekd6/gpsd/blob/2a72f421d01f5dd5809044bf513f315491e0375e/libgps_sock.c).

If you need a fully functional client, I suggest the workaround in my initial comments

> you could use the standard client on the Raspberry Pi and build a new
>   network service on the Raspberry, to which you could connect in a more
>   standard way from c#"

### C# Listener

Otherwise you can try to create just a basic C# Listener: follow the msdn [How-To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
public void createListener()
{
    // Create an instance of the TcpListener class.
    TcpListener tcpListener = null;
    IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
    try
    {
        // Set the listener on the local IP address 
        // and specify the port.
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13);
        tcpListener.Start();
        output = "Waiting for a connection...";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        output = "Error: " + e.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        // Always use a Sleep call in a while(true) loop 
        // to avoid locking up your CPU.
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        // Create a TCP socket. 
        // If you ran this server on the desktop, you could use 
        // Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket() 
        // for greater flexibility.
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        // Read the data stream from the client. 
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        SocketHelper helper = new SocketHelper();
        helper.processMsg(tcpClient, stream, bytes);
    }
}
```

The whole, detailed implementation would be out of scope here.

### A side note

Keep in mind that you need to sleep while looping.

### Likely simpler solution

However, leveraging the native client bindings seems the easier method, at first sight.

For example, the `gps_read()` is described as

> Blocking read for data from the daemon.

The idea here is to call a [C++ wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp) from C# and to write the client's unit operations as described in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000487/6298965)