# C++ print number with decimals

Tags: c++, gps

I have a GPS antenna attached to a Raspberry Pi and tried to get its coordinates through C++ with the gps.h library. In there, the latitude is defined as double. Now, when I tried to print it out using printf, with %d the output is 5 and with %f it's 0.000000. I'm just tying to get the exact number that's behind the latitude.

I live in Switzerland and the latitude here is at around 47 degrees. I think that the latitude is stored as 4.7... and there could be some rounding happening, hence the output 5.

Thanks to everybody

edit:

```
struct gps_data_t gps_d;
printf("%d\n", gps_d.fix.latitude);
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code snippet

Comment: If you are using C++ why are you using printf ? Try to `std::cout << alt << std::endl`

Comment: Printing a `double` with %d is undefined behaviour, the displayed value is rubbish. If you print it with %f and the output is 0.00000, then your variable actually contains 0.0 and you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @Quallentino It seems you just declared a variable without reading any values from your GPS module before printing latitude

Comment: Are you sure you _actually_ read from the GPS? The code you posted suggests you don't. Please post the relevant lines of your _actual_ code. Is `gps_d` a local or a global variable?

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000328/libgps-c-code-example) may be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

I see that gps_d.fix.latitude is a double value, you have to use either %f or %lf to print it using printf. And it also says valid if mode is >=2 so check your code if this is the case. If %f is printing 0.0 then probably the variable value contains actually 0.0.

```
double latitude;    /* Latitude in degrees (valid if mode >= 2) */
```

However, if you are programming in C++ then you can also print as below:

```
std::cout << gps_d.fix.latitude << std::endl;
```

Comment: If you think this solved your question, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jabberwocky. You can try to read the NMEA to check whether the GPS works.

```
cat /dev/<GPS Serial Port>
```